# Facebook app notification sent succesfully, but not received

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm having a rare but important issue with facebook's [notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications). The short story is that a user can request to be notified via Facebook when a specific event occurs. A task is scheduled to periodically check users' notification requests and send each user a notification if the event has occurred. At least one user is not receiving these notifications ever. This is what I know:

- Facebook's response for the notifications that have not arrived was always `{ success: true }`.
- The notifications are sent by a facebook app, not by a facebook user.
- I've tested several other facebook accounts, all of which receive the notifications just fine.
- The account that does not receive the notifications was viewed on desktop (I'm aware that the notifications are not visible on mobile).
- The account that does not receive the notifications has the notifications setting enabled for our app.
- The notifications were sent to the correct app scoped user ID.

Is there anything I'm missing? I know the notifications API is still in beta, could this be related to a bug?

Comment: This might be a bug. I would recommend you file a report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs providing IDs, calls and repro steps to the issue.